# What is `$6$rounds=` when running Passlib with Python?

Tags: python, encryption, passlib

I'm generating SHA-512 encoded password keys with Python's `Passlib`'s command.

`python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; print sha512_crypt.encrypt(getpass.getpass())"`

This is per Ansible documentation: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module).

It prompts for a password, which I input. And then it returns the key.

Regardless of the password I input, all keys created begin with `$6$rounds=...`

What does this mean? Is this part of the key?

Answer (score 3):

This indicates to the schema for the used algorithm. In the case of `sha512_crypt` `6` indicates `sha512` and `rounds=x` indicate the number of rounds to compute the hash.

Also current `NIST` standards suggest `pbkdf2_sha256` for password hashing.

Comment: Should the round be included in the string when using the key?

Comment: @tim_zyx The 'Format' section of passlib's [sha256_crypt manpage](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html#format-algorithm) describes the full format of the hash string. sha512_crypt has the same format, just with $6$ and a longer digest.